# How do I correctly link my PHP file to my CSS

Tags: php, html

For some reason my index.php file won't connect to the CSS despite using what I believe to be the correct browser path.  `<link rel= "stylesheets" media="all" href= "../stylesheets/staff.css" />`  My index.php file is  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Exercise Files/Chapter_01/01_02/basic_php_project/public/index.php  and the CSS is located in  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Exercise Files/Chapter_01/01_02/basic_php_project/public/stylesheets/staff.css  Please can you let me know why this is not connecting?

Comment: Because `..` would take it out of the public directory. Try using `/path/to/folder/file.css`, which would link directly from the document root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your stylesheet is in the same directory as your index.php file. you don't have to use the two dots in your href.

the two dots stent for previous directory

try this: `<link rel= "stylesheets" media="all" href= "/stylesheets/staff.css" />`

Answer (score 0):

Your **CSS file** and **index.php** file existe in the same directory, so why would you use '..', the dots send you back to previous directories.
You can just use : 
`<link rel="stylesheets" media="all" href="/stylesheets/staff.css">`
and you are good to go.